# antd design select filtering not worked

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

First of all i take select.  Inside the select tag I have mapped category showSearch using input field but data is not found when searching.

My code is here..

```
<Select
            bordered={false}
            placeholder="Search to Select"
            size="large"
            showSearch
            className="form-select m-3 w-96 border"
            onChange={(value) => {
              setCategory(value);
            }}
          >
            {categories?.map((c) => (
              <Option key={c._id} value={c._id}>
                {c.name}
              </Option>
            ))}
          </Select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you haven't added the `onSearch` prop, try adding it as:

```
       <Select
            bordered={false}
            placeholder="Search to Select"
            size="large"
            showSearch
            className="form-select m-3 w-96 border"
            onSearch={handleSearch}
            onChange={(value) => {
              setCategory(value);
            }}
          >
            {categories?.map((c) => (
              <Option key={c._id} value={c._id}>
                {c.name}
              </Option>
            ))}
          </Select>
```

And a function to handle search:

```
async function handleSearch(userInput){
     const response = await axios.get("https://test.com",{searchValue: userInput });
     setCategories(response.data);
}
```